Trying to get all user ids from firestore database, so I can access the ratings and combine them,
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { db } from "./firebase/Firebase";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useAuth } from "./AuthContext";

const Ratings = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth(); // Get the currently logged-in user
  const [userRatings, setUserRatings] = useState([]);
  const [userUIDs, setUserUIDs] = useState([]); // State for all user UIDs
  const [loadingRatings, setLoadingRatings] = useState(true); // Loading state for user ratings
  const [loadingUIDs, setLoadingUIDs] = useState(true); // Loading state for user UIDs

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserRatings = async () => {
      if (!currentUser) {
        console.error("No user is logged in.");
        setLoadingRatings(false);
        return;
      }

      try {
        console.log("Fetching ratings for the logged-in user...");
        const userRatingsCollection = collection(
          db,
          "users",
          currentUser.uid,
          "ratings"
        );
        const ratingsSnapshot = await getDocs(userRatingsCollection);

        const ratings = ratingsSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }));

        console.log("Fetched User Ratings:", ratings);
        setUserRatings(ratings);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching user ratings:", error);
      } finally {
        setLoadingRatings(false);
      }
    };

    const fetchAllUserUIDs = async () => {
      try {
        console.log("Fetching all user UIDs...");
        const usersCollection = collection(db, "users"); // Accessing the users collection
        const usersSnapshot = await getDocs(usersCollection); // Fetching all documents

        const uids = usersSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.id); // Extracting the document IDs (user IDs)
        console.log("Fetched User UIDs:", uids);
        setUserUIDs(uids);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching user UIDs:", error);
      } finally {
        setLoadingUIDs(false);
      }
    };

    fetchUserRatings();
    fetchAllUserUIDs();
  }, [currentUser]);

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto p-4">
      <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">Your Ratings</h2>
      {loadingRatings ? (
        <p>Loading your ratings...</p>
      ) : userRatings.length > 0 ? (
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-6">
          {userRatings.map((rating) => (
            <div
              key={rating.id}
              className="border rounded-lg p-4 shadow hover:shadow-lg transition"
            >
              <h3 className="text-lg font-semibold">{rating.itemTitle}</h3>
              <p className="text-gray-700">Rating: {rating.rating}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>No ratings found for your account.</p>
      )}

      <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mt-8">All User UIDs</h2>
      {loadingUIDs ? (
        <p>Loading user UIDs...</p>
      ) : userUIDs.length > 0 ? (
        <ul className="list-disc pl-6">
          {userUIDs.map((uid) => (
            <li key={uid} className="text-gray-700">
              {uid}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      ) : (
        <p>No users found.</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Ratings;

This shows the ratings for the items for the logged in user, but when I try to get user ids from all the registered users from firebase database, I get No users found. This is how the pathing is /users/mu2CXMasv4eBb4qxLYhs8mnKPty2/ratings/1


So how can I get all the user ids or combine all the ratings?
I tried aggregating and averaging ratings across multiple users in Firestore, querying /users/{userId}/ratings subcollections for community ratings.

The document IDs in your users collection are shown in italtics, which means that there are not actual documents there - so getDocs correctly returns no results. If you check the bottom right of the first screenshot, you can also see a warning about that: "This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots". You will need to either create an actual document for each user in users, or store the user IDs in some other way. This has been covered before, so I linked some previous questions/answers.
